# Implementing Search bar to search topic in WPF HelpSystem

Tags: wpf, chm

I have implemented a context sensitive WPF Help System using .chm , which shows specific htm files when F1 is pressed. Now I would like to add a search bar to it to search through all the topics in the .chm file. Is there any reference/suggestion how to do it?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know - there is a fulltext search tab possible for any CHM.

[image]

HH Workshop API documents how to move to the search tab and initiate a search. Unfortunately the initiating a search part has always been broken in HH. The only way around this would be to find the HH window and search pane controls. Then control those controls from your application using via low level Windows API calls.

I translated this for working with Visual Basic 6 a long time ago. So the search string is pushed to the CHM search tab and search is starting.
http://www.help-info.de/en/Help_Info_HTMLHelp/hh_api.htm#Search

Disclaimer: This isn't a product link - only code to help (open source).